# Early results from GroupByKey transform

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

How can I get GroupByKey to trigger early results, rather than wait for all the data to arrive (which in my case is a pretty long time).I tried to split my input PCollection into windows with an early trigger, but it just doesn`t work. It still waits for all the data to arrive before giving out the results.

```java
PCollection<List<String>> input = ...
PCollection<KV<Integer,List<String>>> keyedInput = input.apply(ParDo.of(new AddArbitraryKey()))
keyedInput.apply(Window<KV<Integer,List<String>>>into(
          FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(1)))
         .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()))
         .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO).discardingFiredPanes())
 .apply(GroupByKey.<Integer,List<String>>create())
       .apply(ParDo.of(new RemoveArbitraryKey()))
       .apply(ParDo.of(new FurtherProcessing())
```

I am doing this to prevent [fusing](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#fusion-prevention) . The AddArbitraryKey transform outputs its elements with Timestamp. However, GroupByKey holds up everything until all the data arrives (for all the windows) . Could someone please tell me how i can get it to trigger early. Thank You .

Comment: I just faced the same issue, a simple fixed window doesn't help, a Combine Per Key waits until the end of the bounded collection. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can install a trigger like

```
Repeatedly
  .forever(AfterProcessingTime
    .pastFirstElementInPane()
    .plusDuration(Duration.standardMinutes(1))
  .orFinally(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow())
  .discardingFiredPanes()
```

Or

```
AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
  .withEarlyFirings(
    AfterProcessingTime
      .pastFirstElementInPane()
      .plusDuration(Duration.standardMinutes(1))
```

Comment: This didn`t work for me . The GroupBy transform dispatches results only after all the elements arrive. I applied the Windowing and triggers to the PCollection, just BEFORE the groupby transform. Is that correct ?  My intention is that as soon as all the elements within a time window arrive, the GroupBy should emit its results for that window. Do I have the wrong idea ? Or could you please tell me how I can achieve that ?

Comment: Have you tried `.plusDuration(Duration.ZERO)`? Also, what's your data source? Is it a batch data source?

Comment: Yes, I tried Duration.ZERO . Yes, it is a batch data source , not streaming. So, the PCollection is bounded. Will it work in this case ?

Comment: Batch pipeline usually doesn't need windowing. GBK will wait for all the data until emitting output. If you still need streaming behavior (windowing and triggering), you need to inject a event timestamp (not processing time) for each input element using `outputWithTimestamp`.

Comment: I have used outputWithTimestamp inside my ParDo in this way : processContext.outputWithTimestamp(id,new Instant());  . Is that correct ? Will GBK wait for all data even if Windows and Triggers are used on a bounded PCollection

Comment: `new Instant()` is processing time. You need to use event time so that windowing and triggering are more meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent fusion, it's better to use the transform `Reshuffle.viaRandomKey()` which performs better and makes sure to not introduce any additional triggering delays.

Comment: The GroupBy transform within the Reshuffle becomes a bottleneck ie, it waits till all elements have arrived. I timestamped the elements and applied them to a Window (as shown in the code snippet in my question) before applying the Reshuffle.viaRandomKey.  My intention is that as soon as all the elements within a time window arrive, the GroupBy should emit its results for that window. Do I have the wrong idea ?

Comment: The PCollection I am working with is a bounded PCollection (of a batch pipeline) . Is that making a difference ?

Comment: Batch pipelines optimize for throughput rather than latency, and don't have watermark tracking (partly because typical batch data sources like files have no obvious timestamp ordering and can't provide any useful watermark estimate) - so GroupByKey effectively buffers all data and fires all windows when all of the data has arrived. Is this showing up as a performance problem for your pipeline?

Comment: Yes, in my scenario : the "source" is a webservice which the dataflow program hits (from within a ParDo) to obtain records.That ParDo has a loop inside it, within which it calls the webservice.  The webservice queries a database at its end, and returns data in a sequential manner, but in batches, by using a cursor. Hence this particular ParDo runs on a single worker. This has high fan-out as output() is called within the loop for each record returned in a batch. The next ParDo which processes these records does not scale according to the number of records output by the first ParDo. Fusion ?

Comment: I suspect that fusion might be happening which prevents the next ParDo from scaling, and hence to break it, wanted to group/ungroup. But if GBK waits for all the data to arrive , it prevents the prevents the records that have already arrived from getting passed to the next ParDo. (The webservice takes a long time to complete all its batches and until that happens none of the records are processed further)

Comment: Yeah - in your case fusion is bad, but lack of pipelining between stages is also bad. You can try running the same job with the Dataflow streaming runner (--streaming=true). Of course, best would be if it was possible to just parallelize the loop inside your original ParDo and/or parallelize querying the database.