# Does Google Cloud Dataflow with bounded collection move watermark in batch mode?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a pipeline which read data from a database in a bounded collection. Each element of the collection has a timestamp assigned with `ProcessContext.outputWithTimestamp`. The data is read with a splittable DoFn where `ProcessContext.updateWatermark` is called at the end of `ProcessElement`. In total, the DoFn works with around 100 splits, so it's not a single one.

Later in the pipeline, the following fixed window is defined:

```
Window.<Map.Entry<Key, Long>>into(
    FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(10)))
        .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)
        .triggering(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
            .withEarlyFirings(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(10))))
        .discardingFiredPanes()
```

After the window the collection is combined per key: `Sum.longsPerKey()`

**The problem is that the elements of the collection never pass through the combiner until the collection is fully read. Is it an expected behaviour of Dataflow in the batch mode?** My guess is that Dataflow doesn't compute/move the watermark at all, is it close to the truth?

My question is very similar to [Early results from GroupByKey transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48886943/early-results-from-groupbykey-transform), but in my case, the collection is read by a Splittable DoFn where `ProcessContext.updateWatermark` is called at the end of each element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the expected behavior of a batch mode pipeline, regardless of using a Splittable DoFn.

Typically, all elements pass through each step at a time (altogether). It is possible that results for a window get processed before others, but this has more to do with capacity and distributed execution.

In the end, GroupByKey, or in your case Sum By Key, forces a shuffle operation, which requires all data to be ready before actually executing the SBK transform.

I’d say you are correct, the watermark is not being track for this scenario.

Comment: Thank you! I've also found the clarification in https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/capability-matrix/#cap-full-where. It says "In batch mode, currently watermark progress jumps from the beginning of time to the end of time once the input has been fully consumed".

Answer (score 1):

In a batch pipeline you can think of watermark to move from min to max all at once. So all the windows logically fire at once. As ch_mike mentioned, in batch each stage executes completely before its downstream stage runs. But they elements should pass through the combiner (assuming you are referring to combiner optimization on the 'mapper').