# dataflow streaming job early results

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Related [Early results from GroupByKey transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48886943/early-results-from-groupbykey-transform)

1. Read avro Source Files from GCS in stream mode
2. Filter Experiment Event and Output Key value pair.
   Key ->"experimentId": "aa", "experimentVariant": 2,  "uuid": abbcd
   value-> eventDate
3. Fixed window to buffer elements(60-120 seconds) with discarding panes
4. Combine per key to collect distinct dates.
   Output example ->
   One window result
   Key ->"experimentId": "aa", "experimentVariant": 2,  "uuid": abbcd
   value -> Set("2020-06-01","2020-06-02")
   next window result
   Key ->"experimentId": "aa", "experimentVariant": 2,  "uuid": abbcd
   value -> Set("2020-06-03")
5. write to gcs

issue is combine step does not give output for a long time even though window is of just 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregating steps such as Combine do not give output until the [watermark](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#watermarks-and-late-data) reaches the end of the window (unless non-default triggering is set up). For file-based sources, it can be the case that records are not sorted by timestamp, so the entire file must be read before it is safe to advance the watermark. On Dataflow, you can [see this in the UI](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-monitoring-intf#data_freshness).

Comment: I am using below trigger and also I have thousands of files and it keeps on waiting to get all the data.It should trigger output after reading some files atleast.p.apply("f", Window.<KV<GenericRecord,Set<String>>>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(120))).trigger(AfterEach.inOrder(rtdly.forever(AfterFirst.of(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(10000),APT.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(60)))) .orFinally(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()),rtdly.forever(APT.pastFirstElementInPane() .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(240))))).wal(DR.standardMinutes(10)).dfp())

Comment: The watermark is a promise that it will never output an element of timetamp T. The watermark cannot safely advance until the last record of the last file is read. (If all your inputs are files, it sounds like you should be running this as a batch pipeline.)

Comment: Is it possible to advance the watermark before the last record of the last file?It will keep all the records in memory until then.
Actually use case is of streaming, source files are added every 2 minutes.

Comment: If you are using something like TextIO.ReadAll(), each filename has a timestamp (at which every element in the file will be emitted) and will advance as files are read. If you need something more granular than this, look into using SDFs.