# GroupIntoBatches not flushing batches, waiting for everything to be processed before outputting

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a pipeline reading from a bounded data source. After some processing transforms, I get a PCollection of String, and I want to group these Strings in batches of 100 elements to send them to an API.

According to its documentation, `GroupIntoBatches`, : "Elements are buffered until there are batchSize elements buffered, at which point they are output to the output PCollection."

My input collection is very large, and yet my GroupIntoBatches does not output anything until every input element is received :
[input / output throughput graphs from Dataflow Runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vub3n.png)

At runtime, I can see that nothing is outputted by the `GroupAll` subtask of the `GroupIntoBatches`, even though it clearly has received more than 100 elements for one key - only 3 keys and over 100k elements - .

**So the question is :** How can I force the `GroupIntoBatches` to flush batches as soon as they are full - or every N seconds otherwise ? Do I need to set a window - processing-time window maybe - ? Is it unrelated ?

I know that `GroupIntoBatches` relies on KV, so I generated random keys - between 0 and N - where N=3. I also tried to add a window on processing time with triggering every 5 seconds to force it to flush the batches, but it does not change anything, all batches are only outputted at the end of the full processing

Code sample - with an attempt to use global window - :

```
PCollection<KV<Integer, String>> bod = stringCollec.apply("Add Keys", ParDo.of(new AssignRandomKeys(3)));
bod.apply(
   Window.<KV<Integer, String>>into(new GlobalWindows())
 .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(1)))).withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO).discardingFiredPanes())
.apply(GroupIntoBatches.ofSize(BATCH_SIZE))
.apply("extract", ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<Integer, Iterable<String>>, String>() {
      @ProcessElement
      public void process(ProcessContext c) {
       //send one full batch to API
    }));
```

and my attempt at using processing-time with FixedWindows:

```
PCollection<KV<Integer, String>> bod = stringCollec.
apply("addTime",WithTimestamps.of(us -> new Instant()))
.apply("Add Keys", ParDo.of(new AssignRandomKeys(3)));
bod.apply(
   Window.<KV<Integer, String>>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(4)))
 .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(1)))).withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO).discardingFiredPanes())
.apply(GroupIntoBatches.ofSize(BATCH_SIZE))
.apply("extract", ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<Integer, Iterable<String>>, String>() {
      @ProcessElement
      public void process(ProcessContext c) {
       //send one full batch to API
    }));
```

Comment: Does the second example work if elements are given actual timestamps, like Instant.now()? The windowing looks correct to me, but it might not have any effect if all the elements have identical timestamps, since they would all end up in the same window.

Comment: I was afraid of that, but yes I generated timestamps using Instant.now(), and I logged the timestamps, and they are different so it should be divided into several windows. But I also tried to add a simple `Sum.integersByKey` after the windowing, and I have the same issue - no outputs until the end - , so I guess my issue is indeed linked with the windowing and triggering and not especially with the `GroupIntoBatches`

Comment: @DanielOliveira I edited my post, and to sum up the windowing and triggering are essentially correct, but for batch jobs dataflow does not fire windows until all data has arrived - I couldn't find this in the doc. So windowing and triggering cannot help me force a flush for batch jobs

Comment: According to that explanation, yes it sounds like the problem is just that this is a batch pipeline. If the functionality you need is just the batching functionality, `GroupIntoBatches` should still work as long as you create multiple windows. Elements should be split into batches for each window, it will just all happen at once. If latency is a concern, though, then you should probably switch to a streaming pipeline.

Comment: PS: You may want to add what you found as an answer to your own question instead of an edit, since that's [recommended SO practice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you find an answer yourself.

Comment: Thamk you very much, I am indeed moving to a streaming pipeline - new problems arose from this as the XmlIO transform does not play well as an unbounded streaming source, creating OOM errors but that's a different story -. And thanks for the SO practice guide !

Answer (score 4):

TLDR: This latency is the expected behaviour for batch pipelines, I need to switch to a streaming pipeline

After testing with another Aggregation transform, I noticed that I have the same issue, and triggering does not work as I would have expected for Batch Dataflow jobs. I found a comment on [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48889167/11096322) saying :

- Batch pipelines optimize for throughput rather than latency, and don't have watermark tracking (partly because typical batch data sources like files have no obvious timestamp ordering and can't provide any useful watermark estimate) - so GroupByKey effectively buffers all data and fires all windows when all of the data has arrived. Is this showing up as a performance problem for your pipeline? – jkff

So this latency for window triggering is inherent to batch dataflows, and I assume it also explains why the transform does not flush the batch as soon as they are ready. Given that latency is important in my case - very large file and the API I am writing to has a limited throughput -, I am moving to a streaming pipeline - where it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can pass time to wait parameter (in seconds) to GroupIntoBatches function. Then it transforms pcollection into batches if batch size is equal or greater than the param you pass or the time parameter which you pass is expired. For ex: if you do like pcoll | GroupIntoBatches(300, 5) that means it yields when the bathch size is >= 300 OR 5 sec is elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `--streaming` option help with Flink runner.